Row Totals not Populating in PowerBI chart
I am building a report on PowerBI Desktop.
I have a measure that is producing column totals but is not producing row totals.
Pipeline Target = 
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Calendar'[Day nr] ), 
            CALCULATE (
                SUM('Pipeline Role Targets'[Yearly Target]) / 365,
                USERELATIONSHIP('Opportunity'[Pipeline_Date], 'Calendar'[Date])
            ),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Calendar'[Week] ), 
            CALCULATE (
                SUM('Pipeline Role Targets'[Yearly Target]) / 52,
                USERELATIONSHIP('Opportunity'[Pipeline_Date], 'Calendar'[Date])
            ),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Calendar'[Mon] ), 
            CALCULATE (
                SUM('Pipeline Role Targets'[Yearly Target]) / 12,
                USERELATIONSHIP('Opportunity'[Pipeline_Date], 'Calendar'[Date])
            ),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Calendar'[Quarter] ), 
            CALCULATE (
                SUM('Pipeline Role Targets'[Yearly Target]) / 4,
                USERELATIONSHIP('Opportunity'[Pipeline_Date], 'Calendar'[Date])
            ),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Calendar'[Year] ), 
    
            CALCULATE (
                SUM('Pipeline Role Targets'[Yearly Target]),
                USERELATIONSHIP('Opportunity'[Pipeline_Date], 'Calendar'[Date])
            )
    )


The measure is design to allow for drill up and down functionality based on date grouping (quarter, month, week). I have no issues with column totals with this measure, however, the row totals are not populating.
Would someone be able to guide me on what Im missing here?

in the totals, none of the calendar columns are in scope.
